# How to post image from a form to action as second parameter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been searching to find a jQuery(Ajax) code that can post image from a form(of course the form also has other inputs) to action as **second parameter**.

i also want it to initialize data one by one.are there any solutions to solve my problem?please help me.

Comment: You can use [`formData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to append values to request. Also, you can add [a file to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image, you can use the  `<input>` tag as follows

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```

In your script file use the following code,

```
var formDatas = new FormData();
var uploadFile= $("#fileInput").get(0).files;

if(uploadFile.lenght > 0){
   formDatas.append("uploadFile",uploadFile[0]);
}

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Your_Controller_Name/Your_Action_Name',
        data:formDatas,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    });
```

In the controller you can get image like this

```
if ( System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
{
   var picture =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["uploadFile"];
}
```

Comment: that is good.but it only post the file as separate file. however i found idea from your answer to solve my problem. thanks

Comment: In the Controller you can get other values as well using HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Your_Model_Property_Name"];

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem.

i had created a normal form that had some properties and image file  was among them:

```
        <h1 class="block-header">افزودن گروه</h1>
        <div class="separator"></div>


        <div class="block-standart">

            <div class="form inline">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Product</legend>





                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Name, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Name, new { @class = "text", id = "Name" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Name)
                        </div>
                    </div>







                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Description, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Description, new { @class = "text", id = "description" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Description)
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Keyword, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div id="t">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Keyword, new { @class = "text", id = "Keyword" })
                                @*<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input" />*@
                                @*<input type="text" data-toggle="tags" id="s" />*@

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Like, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Like, new { @class = "text" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Like)
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.DisLike, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.DisLike, new { @class = "text" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.DisLike)
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.URL, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.URL, new { @class = "text" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.URL)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Enable, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Product.Enable, new { @class = "text" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Enable)
                        </div>
                    </div>







                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Tags, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Tags, new { @class = "text", id = "tags" })
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Image, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="file" id="UploadImage" name="UploadImage" />
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Summery, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Product.Summery, new { @class = "text", id = "txtSum" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Summery)
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Price, new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Price, new { @class = "text", id = "price" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Price)
                            <input type="text" id="gi" name="Product.GroupId" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSabt" onclick="ExceptImage();" />
                    </p>
                    <textarea id="e">jg</textarea>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and my controller was:

```
          public ActionResult AddProduct(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase 
    UploadImage)
        {
            ProductRepository blProduct = new ProductRepository();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 product.Image = UploadImage.FileName;
            string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "Files\\UploadImages\\" + 
    UploadImage.FileName;
            UploadImage.InputStream.ResizeImageByWidth(500, path, 
 Utilty.ImageComperssion.Normal);

            if (blProduct.Add(product))
            {
                return MessageBox.Show("محصول با موفقیت ثبت شد", MessageType.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                return MessageBox.Show("محصول ثبت نشد", MessageType.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //مقدار ورودی اشتباه
            return MessageBox.Show(ModelState.GetErrors(), MessageType.Warning);
        }
    }
```

I posted data in 2 steps:

1-i posted all data except the file.

2-i posted the file as separate file.

in step 1 i used onclilck event and used a function called ExceptImage.

in ExceptImage i Used ajax to post all data except the image file:

```
 function ExceptImage(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/AddProduct",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                Name: $("#Name").val(),
                Description: $("#description").val(),
                Keyword: $("#Keyword").val(),
                Like: $("#Product_Like").val(),
                DisLike: $("#Product_DisLike").val(),
                URL: $("#Product_URL").val(),
                Enable: $("#Product_Enable").val(),
                Summery: $("#txtSum").val(),
                Tags: $("#Product_Tags").val(),
                GroupId: $("#gi").val()
            }
        })
    }
```

in step 2 i used form submit event(jQuery) and posted the file:

```
 $("#myUploadForm").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var fd = new FormData(this)
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/AddProduct',
                type: 'POST',
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false

            })
        })
```